# How to create the div structure using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell how to create the below div structure using jquery chaining and with minimal number of code lines.

```html
<div class="pane">
  <h3>Test</h3>
  <p><span class="logo">test</span> 3 mi</p>
  <p class="stores-desc">Testing</p>
  <p class="stores-timing"><strong> Test &nbsp;</strong> 0:00 am - 0:00 pm &nbsp;<strong>tst</strong> 0:00 pm &nbsp;<strong> tstnbsp;</strong> 0:00 am - 0:00 pm</p>
  <div class="store-checkin">Click here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you want to create that in jQuery if you already have in HTML?

Comment: Need to pass the JSON data into it and it's the requirement.

Comment: You can simply edit elements with [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) calling them by id or class. You don't need to create all the structure. Example: `$(".pane h3").text("NEW TEXT");`

Comment: Why create it when you can call `.html()` on an element and get the HTML structure. And @GerardCuadras beat me to it.

Comment: I have implemented the way you are suggesting, but it's the req so I need to create it in jquery like see the below example. var str = $('<div/>').addClass('pane') like that I want please help me out.

Comment: Ok... so if you want to create all the structure you will need to check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

Comment: Thanks for that, just stucked here see the below code var stre= $('<div/>').addClass('pane').after('<h3/>').text("test"); can you tell how to add h3 tag within the div tag, the above one is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are better, faster, ways to do this with less code.  This particularly looks like a problem best solved with a template based solution.  However, if you want to use jQuery fluent syntax to construct that snippet then here is one way.

```js
var myHtml = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("pane")
    .append( $("<h3/>").text("Test") )
    .append(
      $("<p/>")
        .append( $("<span />").addClass("logo").text("test") )
        .append( " 3 mi" )
    )
    .append( $("<p/>").addClass("stores-desc").text("Testing") )
    .append(
      $("<p/>").addClass("stores-timing")
        .append( $("<strong />").html(" Test &nbsp;") )
        .append( "0:00 am - 0:00 pm &nbsp;" )
        .append( $("<strong />").text("tst") )
        .append( " 0:00 pm &nbsp;" )
        .append( $("<strong />").text("tst") )
        .append( " 0:00 am - 0:00 pm" )
    )
    .append( $("<div/>").addClass("store-checkin").text("Click here") );

$("body").append(myHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```